# MKV player in my iOS app

Tags: ios, video-player, mkv

How can I play mkv video into my iOS App?
Can I use `MPMoviePlayerController` and add to it mkv codecs?

I try to load an mkv from an URL into my `MPMoviePlayerController`

```
NSURL *videoStreamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mkvURL"];
mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoStreamURL];
```

But a black screen, with nothing in it to play, appears.

Comment: Probably not, i dont think you can add Codecs to the base media stuff. Also MKV isnt a codec but a wrapper.

Comment: You perfectly right about the wrapper thing...so what could I do to reproduce mkv in my app?

Comment: how to solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no.

You can use FFMPEG to accomplish this using https://github.com/iMoreApps/ffmpeg-avplayer-for-ios

Comment: Have you ever used it?

Comment: I've used FFMpeg in different capacities and built custom players, however this looks like the simplest option to meet your requirements in a simple api and package.

Comment: Could you send me the simplest demo you can do? I don't need special commands like subtitle ecc ecc, just play pause and stop.

Comment: I downloaded FFMPEG and there is  an example in so I tried to import the minimum required into a new test project. When I run the app I got an error which says that Audio unit framework is missing even if there actually is...that's why I asked you a demo...sorry...